# Comparing number of multiplications to compute $a^{2^n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Compare the number of multiplications used by both algorithms below to evaluate $a^{2^n}$,

[image]

And the second algorithm to evaluate $a^{2^n}$,

[image]

The first algorithm will yield $2^n$ multiplications while the second one will yield only $n$ multiplications.

**Question 1**: I am trying to understand why the first algorithm does $2^n$ multiplications while the second one does $n$ multiplications.  In my attempt to find out the number of multiplications, I find that the first algorithm does the following multiplications,

$$n = 1\longrightarrow (a\cdot 1),~~1 ~~ multiplication$$
$$n = 2\longrightarrow a\cdot (a\cdot 1),~~ 2 ~~ multiplication$$
$$\cdots$$
$$n = k\longrightarrow a\cdots(a\cdot 1),~~ k ~~ multiplication$$

So how the first algorithm does the $2^n$?

**Question 2**: similarly, for the second algorithm,
$$n = 1\longrightarrow (a\cdot a),~~1 ~~ multiplication$$
$$n = 2\longrightarrow (a\cdot a)^2=(a\cdot a)(a\cdot a),~~ 3 ~~ multiplication$$
$$n = 3\longrightarrow ((a\cdot a)(a\cdot a))^2=(a\cdot a)(a\cdot a)(a\cdot a)(a\cdot a),~~ 7 ~~ multiplication$$
$$\cdots$$

So I am not sure why the second algorithm only does $n$ multiplications?

Comment: A squaring is a multiplication. Consider $a^{2^4}=(((a^2)^2)^2)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first algorithm is essentially
$$\underbrace{a \cdot \ldots \cdot a}_{2^n \text{ times}},$$
so you do $2^n$ multiplications (multiplying with $a$ every time). The second algorithm does
$$(\ldots((a\overbrace{^2)^2)\ldots)^2}^{n \text{ times}},$$
so you are multiplying the result with itself $n$ times (not with $a$). That's the difference.

Comment: Thank you. That really helps alot. Last thing, could you please explain why we need $n$ times in the second algorithm as evaluating $a^2$ does also need 2 multiplications, so why it's excluded from the answer please?

Comment: $a^2 = a \cdot a$, that's only one multiplication I would say.

Comment: I got that, so it's $n$ times multiplied by $1$, which is $n$ multiplications total.